# Jquery Mobile Listview Clicked Item - Pass parameter to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, listview, jquery-mobile

I've a index.html page. Also this page contains lots of page like #home, #list #contacts etc.

in #list part i dynamically get data from my webpage and generate listview. I want that, when user click any of list item, redirect to #imageDetail page and pass image URL to page and show image

here is the #imageDetail page part

```
    <div data-role="page"  id="detailedIMAGE" data-theme="a">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Image Detail</h1>
        </div>
            <div data-role="content">       
            <img id="imageDetayURL" name="imageDetayURL" src="glyphish-icons/158-wrench-2.png"/>
            <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="brewername" name="brewername" />
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

And below code is my javascript code to get json data dynamically.

```
    <script>
    $('#last5').live("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mysqlservice.com/getdata.json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json_results){
                $("#imageListDetay").html('');
                console.log(json_results);
                $('#imageListDetay').append('<ul data-role="listview" id="tweetul" data-theme="c"></ul>');
                listItems = $('#imageListDetay').find('ul');
                $.each(json_results.results, function(key) {
                    html = '<h3>'+json_results.results[key].screen_name+'</h3><span id="detailed_image">'+json_results.results[key].resim_url+'</span><img WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=100 src="http://mywebpage.org/upload/'+json_results.results[key].resim_url+'" /><p class="ui-li-bside"><img WIDTH=8 HEIGHT=13 src="images/07-map-marker.png"/> '+json_results.results[key].adres_data+'</p>';
                    listItems.append('<li><a  name="imageDetayGoster" href="#detailedIMAGE">'+html+'</a></li>');
               });
                $('#imageListDetay ul').listview();
            },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //error
            }
        });
    })


    $("#detailedIMAGE").live("pagebeforeshow", function (e, data) { 
         var brewername = $('#detailed_image',data.prevPage).text();
         $('#brewername').val(brewername);  
         $('#imageDetayURL').attr('src', 'http://mobil.harmankaya.org/'+brewername);
         alert(brewername);
     });
    </script>
```

The problem is after page change `alert(brewername)` fires. But **list all image** urls that listed in listview not my selected.

How can i fixed this issue

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're still having issues with this, please feel free to check out my [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which allows for clean URL navigation with parameters

Answer (score 1):

jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-dynamic.html

This is just quoting the docs but if you read the page it should give you an idea on how to accomplish this.

> The application uses links with urls that contain a hash that tells
>   the application what category items to display:

```
<h2>Select a Category Below:</h2>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#category-items?category=animals">Animals</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-items?category=colors">Colors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#category-items?category=vehicles">Vehicles</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If you are new to jQuery and jQuery Mobile, please search google for documentation about it before going out and make an app using these libraries

Comment: @aki any developer always try to understand all this and then he ask for help.don't be so rude.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is my way and works very good.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
<div data-role="content" id="myContent">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true/false/whatever" id="myList"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#myPage").live("pageshow",function(event){
       // get your id from LINK and parse it to a variable
    var json_list_callback = getUrlVars()[id];

       // verify the URL id
    if (json_list_callback === '') {json_list_callback === ''} //or what value you want

       // define your path to JSON file generated by the ID declared upper
    var json_URL = 'http://your.path.to.json.file.php.json?id=' + json_list_callback;

       // get the JSON data defined earlier and append to your LIST
    $.getJSON(json_URL,function(data){
        var entries = data;
        //populate our list with our json data
        $.each(entries,function(index,entry){
                // i use dummy data here, you can have whatever you want in youre json
            $("#myList").append(
               '<li>' +
                        // remember that this "page.html?id=' + entry.json_id + '" will be the link where getUrlVars will get the id declared earlier in function
                  '<a href="page.html?id=' + entry.json_id + '">' + entry.json_title + '<\/a>' +
               '<\/li>'
            );
        });
          //must refresh listview for layout to render
        $("#myList").listview("refresh");
    });
});
    //this function gets from URL the id, category, whatever you declare like this: getUrlVars()['id'] or getUrlVars()['category'] after last symbol of "?"
    // you can define your own symbol with this function
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = [],
    hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
```

This works for me like a charm and i'm using it very often!

Comment: Thanks but it is now clear for me. How can i implement your solution to my code. I'm really confused.

Comment: The method described upper is to populate a list with JSON entries through a variable. You can addapt the code very well to your needs. I commented the code to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

live event has been deprecated, use 'on',

exmple:  $("#detailedIMAGE").on("pagebeforeshow", function (e, data){  // code });