# JQuery Mobile strange behavior, select's onchange event goes back all the time (only on SAFARI IPHONE)

Tags: jquery, iphone, select, mobile, behavior

I've developed a dynamic website for a local newspaper in greece and I have the following strange behavior on its mobile edition (jquery mobile):

1. I have a select on top of every page with the categories (top right) and when I select from there any category, I catch the onchange event and take the value of the option which contains the destination url. The page changed but immediately goes back to the original (caller) page.
2. I have inside the page a list view with the same urls as the top select (categories) and if I click on that links (from the list view) everythings goes fine.

**3. This behavior ONLY can be reproduced from any IPHONE SAFARI browser.**

I read some answers more or less with the same problem, but any workaround has worked for me. the url of the mobile version is: http://m.stagonnews.gr

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use on onChange event fired by select the next method? $.mobile.changePage( "your_url_page.html" );

Comment: The code is the following: $(document).ready(function() {  

    $("select[name=select-choice-a]").change(function(event) {        

      $.mobile.changePage('#'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
 
    });

  }); I also tried: $.mobile.changePage(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
and window.location.hash = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

Answer (score 1):

Do not use $(document).ready() function!

jQuery Mobile docs offer a documentation about this! It fires everytime you change the page and because poping dialog doesn't record into the history it can redirect you into it, probably. Doc [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html)

Use the live initalization on your select field, similar to this:

```
   //on all pages you have a div with data-role="header" | assign an id to it
   //if this doesn't work, assign the live eventto your page id, not header id
$('#your_header_id').live('pageshow',function (event) { //or 'pagecreate'
       //load function and fire the changing event when user changes the select
   $('select[name=select-choice-a]').change(function(event){
       //make sure it returns the exact value of select
        //if not, there is a problem in your select value method
      console.log('Change to page: #' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);

       //to the change page method that changes the page
        //you could also do the $.mobile.loadPage method to insert it into DOM before change
      $.mobile.changePage('#' + this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,{changeHash: false})
   })
});
```

My opinion about using anchors (#element_id's) into a mobile app developed with jQuery Mobile is this: DONT!, but this is just my opinion!
I use specific HTML files and point link to them! To pass parameter to another page and retrieve it, i use a specific function that returns to me the parameter itself and do the cool nice stuff with it. I posted on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083887/925058) what is that function and how you can use it. Then i change pages just with $.mobile.changePage('myPage.html?id=' + variable).

I use this method because i can structure my app very well with limited of data and i can controll all of my html files with one javascript file, with .live events.

A short brief:

```
index.html <- load all javascripts/css/whatever here
other_file.html <- declare only <html><head></head><body> jQM specific div's here (like <div data-role"page"></div> etc,)</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot aki. But still have problems: Change to page: #/el/current/greece/ (this is ok!) but after this when tries to changePage I obtain this the same STRANGE behavior: goes back to the caller page!!! I also tried without # and the same occured. Try please the page: http://m.stagonnews.gr and click top right on any option (try 3rd or 4th for example).

Comment: Well, the new approach seems like working now. I tested on my iPhone and without error.

Comment: Thanks, @aki.  $.mobile.changePage() has solved similar problems for me with dialogue display on Android!